# Need help for fadeout the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to fade in/out the class about div using js function provided. But this method is not working i need some solution for this problem.
your solution will be kindly appreciated.

ASPX FILE :

```
<body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server" >
 <div>
    <input class="btn1" type="button" value="button" />
    <input class="btn2" type="button" value="button" />

    <div class="about" runat="server" >
        <div class="style2">
            <strong><span class="style3">About</span></strong>
         </div>
         <hr />
         <p class="style2">
            About DIV
         </p>
     </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

JAVA Script file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".btn1").click(function () {
            $(".about").fadeOut()
        });
        $(".btn2").click(function () {
            $(".about").fadeIn();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/3Lbjx249/ What do you mean "not working"

Comment: not working = when i click button i am not able to see any animation i.e fade in or fade out

Comment: As you can see the example in jsfiddle works, are there any errors in your console?

Comment: its seems working good in jsfiddle but not in vs :/ do i need to download any script ?

Comment: thanks chris charles :) for your co-operation i missed linking js file :/ but working awesome now

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you are importing jquery

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

And take a look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/3Lbjx249/